# Getting inner exception "dtd is prohibited in this xml document exchange" while reading emails from outlook

Tags: c#, windows-services, exchangewebservices

Getting error "The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML." with 
inner exception "dtd is prohibited in this xml document exchange" while reading 
emails from outlook(Not while reading every mail). 
Can anybody  please tell me what might be the issue. Below is the code where I am 
getting error

```
FindItemsResults<Item> RetrievedItems=null ;

RetrievedItems = service.FindItems(FIds, new ItemView(4));
String[] SignatureList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SignatureTypes").Split(',');



if (RetrievedItems != null && RetrievedItems.Count() > 0)
{

 RetrievedItems.ToList().ForEach(x =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
List<String> Attachments = new List<String>();
List<String> ScanFileName = new List<String>();

 bool IsAvailable = true;

//Getting error while Load() - below line of code                         
                            ((Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage)x).Load();

Vo.EmailMessage msg = new Vo.EmailMessage();
                            msg.MessageId = ((Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage)x).Id.UniqueId;
                            msg.From = ((Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage)x).From.Address;
                            ((Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage)x).ToRecipients.ToList().ForEach(z => msg.To += z.Address + ",");
                            ((Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage)x).ReplyTo.ToList().ForEach(y => msg.ReplyToEmailAddress += y.Address + ",");
                            msg.Subject = ((Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage)x).Subject;
                            msg.Body = ((Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage)x).Body.Text;
                            msg.Dated = ((Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage)x).DateTimeSent;
```

Comment: Did you see this question? It seems similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939038/am-getting-invalid-xml-as-a-response-from-ews-calls

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen this error. What I have found is that making the exact same call even 1 second later and it works. I've worked with Microsoft, and their "feeling" is that an intermediary device [in my case an F5] is modifying the payload before the Exchange Server gets it. I do know that if we bypass the F5 completely, the problem goes away.